# remove outer border line from .mdl-layout__drawer-button in material design?

Tags: html, css, button, navigation, material-design

I want to remove the outer border from the **.mdl-layout__drawer-button** .
When ever i click it it shows me outer square box.
I am referring [this site](https://getmdl.io/components/#layout-section). 
Below is the code and screenshot for it:

[image: This is the Image when i left click on it or right click it will display the sqaure box]

```
<!-- Uses a transparent header that draws on top of the layout's background -->
<style>
.demo-layout-transparent {
  background: url('../assets/demos/transparent.jpg') center / cover;
}
.demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__header,
.demo-layout-transparent .mdl-layout__drawer-button {
  /* This background is dark, so we set text to white. Use 87% black instead if
     your background is light. */
  color: white;
}
</style>

<div class="demo-layout-transparent mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--transparent">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Title</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="">Link</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these styles to your button class-
outline:none;
focus:none;

Comment: Thanks @sahil it worked for me , thanks for helping me out

Answer (score 2):

add to your mdl-layout__drawer-button class:

```
outline: none;
```

Answer (score 2):

Particular Menu tag add style

> outline:0;

OR

> style:"outline:0;" inline on tag

Comment: Welcome @MDShahrouq